# Internet conection timing out on one laptop only

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, sony-vaio

I've just moved house and had ADSL broadband installed 3 days ago. The router is a new Netgear DGN1000SP from Virgin Media. It works fine on my android phone, work mac laptop and an old win7 vaio.
My new Vaio, which I need most, isn't working. It sometimes works for a couple of requests, but then hangs and from then on all internet connections time out.
I have updated the Network adapters drivers. The connection is perfect when wired into the router so it is definitely a wifi issue.

Below is a screengrab of two pings that I ran simultaneously, one from the router and one from the laptop - the router is successful but the laptop is timing out.
Strangely, the Intel PROSet wireless diagnostic is showing all green, I ran it immediately after the pings.

Wifi: Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235
Laptop: Vaio S series, Win7 64 bit, CPU i5-3210M 2x2.50GHz, 6.00 GB RAM

[image: Diagnostic]
[image: Pings]

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable the IPV 6. 
If that doesn't work, try to disable IEEE 802.1x authentication for that network.

Comment: Thanks again @Rujke. Whilst looking for these settings I tried changing the wireless network mode on the router to 'g&b' and it seems to have worked! It was previously 'up to 150Mbps'. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You should give instructions on how to do this, to help those that don't know how.

Comment: @robC I actually meant Rujke but glad to hear that you fixed the issue.

Comment: @KronoS will do next time

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reset IP adress on your laptop? If so, try adding premission for your laptop in NETGEAR SW with MAC address.

Comment: Hi thanks, I did ipconfig /renew. I turned on Access control and added the MAC address to 'trusted wireless stations'. Still times out.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the wireless mode on the router. Log in by visiting 192.168.0.1 and click on 'Wireless Settings'. Under the 'Wireless Network' section change the 'mode' option, for me it worked on 'g & b'.